# Returning text with complex formatting via INDEX(MATCH)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using the following formula to return a string of text from table `MasterKit` dependent on what Item is selected in that row.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(MasterKit[Note],MATCH([@Item],MasterKit[Item],0)),"")
```

The cell it calls is formatted with some text in red, some underlined, some italics etc.

- Is it possible for the returned text in the formula cell to be formatted precisely as it is in the cell it calls?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you agree to use VBA, it's "simple"...

Comment: I feared such. I should probably have a pass at this VBA thing. 
@user3514930 How bad would it be?

Comment: @DaveRGP In order to retain that kind of formatting, you need to have a text string (and not a formula) in the destination cell.  So you need to write a VBA Macro that accomplishes the same goal as your worksheet formula; if you do a copy/paste operation from the source, it should retain the differential formatting.  Otherwise you may need to go character-by-character